# Print job error information on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-printer

When a print job goes to "error" status, is there any way to get more detailed information on what exactly went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 Event log would have operational log for the print job, but first you need to enable it.
See the following thread:

[Windows 7 and print jobs logging](https://serverfault.com/questions/459958/windows-7-and-print-jobs-logging)